# Last week most viewed Items using Impressionist gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I have Post model and It's `impressionable` using [Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem
I want to show top 10 most visited Post in last month.

Here is the way I came up with:

```
Post.all.sort_by{|post| post.view_count_last_month}.first 10
```

and `view_count_last_month`method is in `Post` model:

```
def view_count_last_week
    impressionist_count(:start_date => 1.week.ago)
end
```

But I think it's not good for performance because It loads all the Posts and then sort them by `view_count_last_month` method.

What is the best way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By looking at the [Impressionist](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist) gem code for [association](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/master/lib/impressionist/is_impressionable.rb#L15-L20) and in [impressionist_count](https://github.com/charlotte-ruby/impressionist/blob/master/app/models/impressionist/impressionable.rb#L31-L49), you can actually create your own scope like this:

```
  scope :order_by_starting_at, -> (start_date){ 
    impressions_table = Impression.quoted_table_name

    query = if start_date.present?
      "#{impressions_table}.created_at >= '#{start_date}' AND "
    else
      ''
    end

    query += "#{impressions_table}.created_at <= '#{Time.now}'"

    order(%Q{
            COALESCE((
              SELECT
                COUNT(#{impressions_table}.impressionable_id)
              FROM
                #{impressions_table}
              JOIN
                #{Post.quoted_table_name} AS popular_posts
              ON
                popular_posts.id = #{impressions_table}.impressionable_id
              AND
                #{impressions_table}.impressionable_id = '#{self.to_s}'
              WHERE
                #{query}
             ), 0) DESC
          })
    }

  scope :view_counts_for_first,-> (number){  
    order_by_starting_at.limit(number) 
    }
```

now you can:

```
Post.order_by_starting_at(1.week.ago).limit(10)
Post.order_by_starting_at.limit(10)
```

EDIT:

However, it turned out that this worked even better -

```
Post.joins(:impressions).where("impressions.created_at<='#{Time.now}' and impressions.created_at >= '#{start_time}'").group("impressions.impressionable_id").order("count(impression‌​s.id) DESC")
```

Comment: I accepted your answer but when I tested there was a problem.
The Active Relation result is not sorted. I can't understand why?

Comment: Ok, what's the query being generated?

Comment: SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" ORDER BY 
 COALESCE((
 SELECT
 COUNT("impressions".impressionable_id)
 FROM
 "impressions"
 JOIN
 "posts" AS popular_posts
 ON
 popular_posts.id = "impressions".impressionable_id
 AND
 "impressions".impressionable_id = 'Post'
 WHERE
 "impressions".created_at >= '2014-08-22 12:04:29 UTC' AND "impressions".created_at <= '2014-08-29 16:34:29 +0430'
 ), 0) DESC

Comment: Can you please try this: `Post.joins(:impressions).group("impressions.impressionable_id").order("count(impressions.id) DESC")` and tell me the query being generated?

Comment: Post.joins(:impressions).where("impressions.created_at<='#{Time.now}' and impressions.created_at >= '#{start_time}'").group("impressions.impressionable_id").order("count(impressions.id) DESC")
Works! I think you should update your answer! thank you!

Comment: There is no column impression‌​s.id for me.

Comment: I had to change the `order` to `.order("count(#{self.table_name}.id) DESC")` what makes sense with group.

Comment: @b1nary : Glad that it worked for you. However, I would encourage you to you use `self. quoted_table_name` instead of `self.table_name` because it would quote your table name when it generates the SQL and will likely to run to chances where table names matches with a keyword. Nothing big, but more like one of the good practices to follow. :)